# OSPF NSSA load balancing

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf

I have a OSPF network partitioned onto 2 areas as shown in the Figure below.
[image]

Area 4 is configured as a NSSA with no-summary which receives only default route. Routers R3, R4, R5 are redistributing the same IP address 100.0.0.1 (locally configured Loopback interface). My problem is that R2 installs 3 routes (OSPF NSSA external type 2) to the destinations and R1 installs only one (OSPF external type 2).

R2 routing table:

```
R2#show ip route 
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       1.1.1.1 [110/2] via 10.0.12.1, 00:10:38, FastEthernet0/1
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       2.2.2.2 is directly connected, Loopback0
     100.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O N2    100.0.0.1 [110/20] via 10.0.99.5, 00:03:45, FastEthernet0/0
                  [110/20] via 10.0.99.4, 00:04:14, FastEthernet0/0
                  [110/20] via 10.0.99.3, 00:04:33, FastEthernet0/0
     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       3.3.3.3 [110/2] via 10.0.99.3, 00:11:17, FastEthernet0/0
     4.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       4.4.4.4 [110/2] via 10.0.99.4, 00:11:17, FastEthernet0/0
     5.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       5.5.5.5 [110/2] via 10.0.99.5, 00:11:18, FastEthernet0/0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.0.12.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
C       10.0.27.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
O       10.0.16.0/30 [110/2] via 10.0.12.1, 00:10:40, FastEthernet0/1
O       10.0.67.0/30 [110/2] via 10.0.27.2, 00:11:28, FastEthernet1/0
C       10.0.99.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

R1 routing table:

```
R1#show ip route 
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       1.1.1.1 is directly connected, Loopback0
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       2.2.2.2 [110/2] via 10.0.12.2, 00:12:06, FastEthernet0/1
     100.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O E2    100.0.0.1 [110/20] via 10.0.99.5, 00:05:02, FastEthernet0/0
     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       3.3.3.3 [110/2] via 10.0.99.3, 00:12:06, FastEthernet0/0
     4.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       4.4.4.4 [110/2] via 10.0.99.4, 00:12:06, FastEthernet0/0
     5.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       5.5.5.5 [110/2] via 10.0.99.5, 00:12:07, FastEthernet0/0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.0.12.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
O       10.0.27.0/30 [110/2] via 10.0.12.2, 00:12:07, FastEthernet0/1
C       10.0.16.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
O       10.0.67.0/30 [110/2] via 10.0.16.2, 00:12:07, FastEthernet1/0
C       10.0.99.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

I understand that one of the routers performs Type7/5 translation (in that case R2 as it has higher router-id) therefore it installs 3 all the routes.

My question is, is it possible to load balance the traffic so that all the 3 routes are installed on R1 as well? If not, would it be possible to remove the route to 100.0.0.1 from R1 so that the traffic goes via R2 only (PBR is not an option in my case).

Router configurations:

```
*********         R1        *************
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 1 area 0
!         
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.99.1 255.255.255.0
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!         
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.252
 ip ospf 1 area 0
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.0.16.1 255.255.255.252
 ip ospf 1 area 0     
!         
router ospf 1
 router-id 1.1.1.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 4 nssa no-summary
!
*********         R2        *************
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 1 area 0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.99.2 255.255.255.0
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.12.2 255.255.255.252
 ip ospf 1 area 0
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.0.27.1 255.255.255.252
 ip ospf 1 area 0
!
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 2.2.2.2
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 4 nssa no-summary
!
*********         R3        *************
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 100.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.99.3 255.255.255.0
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 3.3.3.3
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 4 nssa no-summary
 redistribute connected subnets
!
*********         R4        *************
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 100.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.99.4 255.255.255.0
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 4.4.4.4
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 4 nssa no-summary
 redistribute connected subnets
!
*********         R5        *************
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 5.5.5.5 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 100.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.99.5 255.255.255.0
 ip ospf 1 area 4
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 5.5.5.5
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 4 nssa no-summary
 redistribute connected subnets
```

show ip ospf database:

R1

```
R1# show ip ospf database 

            OSPF Router with ID (1.1.1.1) (Process ID 1)

        Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         35          0x80000003 0x00A5F4 3
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         34          0x80000003 0x00E88E 3
10.0.67.1       10.0.67.1       39          0x80000003 0x00FAB3 2
10.0.67.2       10.0.67.2       40          0x80000003 0x00F79D 2

        Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.12.2       2.2.2.2         37          0x80000001 0x00AC64
10.0.16.2       10.0.67.1       41          0x80000001 0x00EE91
10.0.27.2       10.0.67.2       40          0x80000001 0x00ABC3
10.0.67.2       10.0.67.2       44          0x80000001 0x00748C

        Summary Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
3.3.3.3         1.1.1.1         25          0x80000001 0x00F436
3.3.3.3         2.2.2.2         35          0x80000001 0x00D650
4.4.4.4         1.1.1.1         39          0x80000001 0x00C660
4.4.4.4         2.2.2.2         39          0x80000001 0x00A87A
5.5.5.5         1.1.1.1         39          0x80000001 0x00988A
5.5.5.5         2.2.2.2         39          0x80000001 0x007AA4
10.0.99.0       1.1.1.1         80          0x80000001 0x00AD1D
10.0.99.0       2.2.2.2         83          0x80000001 0x008F37

        Router Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         42          0x80000002 0x00CB74 1
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         43          0x80000002 0x008DA9 1
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         43          0x80000002 0x00D041 2
4.4.4.4         4.4.4.4         52          0x80000002 0x00E420 2
5.5.5.5         5.5.5.5         51          0x80000002 0x00F8FE 2

        Net Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.99.5       5.5.5.5         43          0x80000002 0x00ACB7

        Summary Net Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
0.0.0.0         1.1.1.1         86          0x80000001 0x001B17
0.0.0.0         2.2.2.2         89          0x80000001 0x00FC31

        Type-7 AS External Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
100.0.0.1       3.3.3.3         86          0x80000001 0x006CAC 0
100.0.0.1       4.4.4.4         97          0x80000001 0x008090 0
100.0.0.1       5.5.5.5         94          0x80000001 0x009474 0

        Type-5 AS External Link States

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
100.0.0.1       2.2.2.2         29          0x80000001 0x0051D1 0
```

R2

```
R2#show ip ospf database 

            OSPF Router with ID (2.2.2.2) (Process ID 1)

        Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         72          0x80000003 0x00A5F4 3
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         69          0x80000003 0x00E88E 3
10.0.67.1       10.0.67.1       76          0x80000003 0x00FAB3 2
10.0.67.2       10.0.67.2       75          0x80000003 0x00F79D 2

        Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.12.2       2.2.2.2         72          0x80000001 0x00AC64
10.0.16.2       10.0.67.1       77          0x80000001 0x00EE91
10.0.27.2       10.0.67.2       75          0x80000001 0x00ABC3
10.0.67.2       10.0.67.2       80          0x80000001 0x00748C

        Summary Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
3.3.3.3         1.1.1.1         62          0x80000001 0x00F436
3.3.3.3         2.2.2.2         70          0x80000001 0x00D650
4.4.4.4         1.1.1.1         75          0x80000001 0x00C660
4.4.4.4         2.2.2.2         73          0x80000001 0x00A87A
5.5.5.5         1.1.1.1         75          0x80000001 0x00988A
5.5.5.5         2.2.2.2         73          0x80000001 0x007AA4
10.0.99.0       1.1.1.1         117         0x80000001 0x00AD1D
10.0.99.0       2.2.2.2         115         0x80000001 0x008F37

        Router Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1         79          0x80000002 0x00CB74 1
2.2.2.2         2.2.2.2         76          0x80000002 0x008DA9 1
3.3.3.3         3.3.3.3         78          0x80000002 0x00D041 2
4.4.4.4         4.4.4.4         87          0x80000002 0x00E420 2
5.5.5.5         5.5.5.5         87          0x80000002 0x00F8FE 2

        Net Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.99.5       5.5.5.5         77          0x80000002 0x00ACB7

        Summary Net Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
0.0.0.0         1.1.1.1         122         0x80000001 0x001B17
0.0.0.0         2.2.2.2         121         0x80000001 0x00FC31

        Type-7 AS External Link States (Area 4)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
100.0.0.1       3.3.3.3         120         0x80000001 0x006CAC 0
100.0.0.1       4.4.4.4         131         0x80000001 0x008090 0
100.0.0.1       5.5.5.5         128         0x80000001 0x009474 0

        Type-5 AS External Link States

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
100.0.0.1       2.2.2.2         63          0x80000001 0x0051D1 0
```

UPDATE

So I found partial solution to the problem. In case the load sharing is not possible I wanted to route the traffic through one of the routers (R1 or R2) only. This is possible if we suppress forwarding address on R2. This forces other routers in Area 0 to use R2 as a gateway to the 100.0.0.1 IP address.

Following command has to be added on R2.

```
router ospf 1
 area 4 nssa translate type7 suppress-fa
```

Comment: Can you post the output of show ip ospf database?

Comment: Hi Ron. I have just pasted the outputs.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed one problem in your configuration. Your ASBRs (R3-5) and ABRs (R1-2) are configured with `area 4 nssa no-summary`
According to configuration guide of NSSA area http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/6208-nssa.html you shoud issue no-summary only on ABRs.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error. Indeed, only ABRs are supposed to be configured with `nssa no-summary`. However this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I did lab this topology up and I'm getting the 3 routes installed on both R1 and R2 as you want.

What's the output of `show ip ospf | i NSSA`?

It should be

```
R1#show ip ospf | i NSSA
 Supports NSSA (compatible with RFC 3101)
        It is a NSSA area
```

If the output says RFC 1587 you have to disable it under the OSPF process

```
router ospf 1  
 no compatible rfc1587
```